# Postgresql error on inserting new row 'PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am just migrate my us server to an eu region on `heroku`, and `restore` the old `database backup` to new server. Unfortunately I am getting following `error` while try to `insert an new row` to one of table

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "id", ...) VALUES ($1, $2, ...) [["created_at", Thu, 13 Oct 2016 23:53:17 CEST +02:00], ["id", nil], ...]

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, ...)
```

My schema looks like following

```
create_table "users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
   t.integer  "id",          :null => false  
   t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
   ...
end
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried following solutions to solve this issues, I am writing down those for who need it.

**Solution#1**

drop my local database

```
rake db:drop
```

run migrations

```
rake db:migrate
```

now import the production database with the `--data-only` option

```
pg_restore --data-only --verbose --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U user_name -d database_name latest.dump
```

*It's partially solve my problem but `lose all my data` in the table, so `this is not an suitable one`.*

**Solution#2 (working fine)**

After observing the errors I understand some things like primary key sequence is break and and system should not try to insert null value to the ID field and some how my `model forgot the primary key`. and then I `set the primary key` through model and its `working fine`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'id'
end
```

Comment: You forgot to recreate the db
`rails db:create`

Comment: If I push this changes to heroku do you think it will affect the database?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same weird problem, and got it solved by a slight variant of your first solution:

```
rake db:drop
```

Then

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

And finally

```
pg_restore --verbose --data-only --disable-triggers --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U user_name -d database_name latest.dump
```

This way, it keeps the database structure, only restores the data, but, by not checking the foreign key constraints, it can load the tables, and doesn't end with a bunch of empty tables...

Comment: If I push this changes to heroku do you think it will affect the database?

Answer (score 0):

Work around for the above issue. I was having the same issue and this and it worked

```
class UserManager < ApplicationRecord
 self.primary_key = 'id'

 before_save :increment_id

 def increment_id
  self.id = UserManager.last.id + 1
 end
end
```